# TCPDF: How to embed and link multiple document types with meaningful icons?

Tags: php, excel, pdf, attachment, tcpdf

I'm trying to embed multiple files within a PDF in TCPDF. What I want to achive is a XLSX icon linked to an embedded Excel file, a PDF-Icon for a PDF file and the same for a PPT-File. On click the files should be opened. What is important is, that these files are really embedded in the PDF and not referenced by a link to the internet.

To add files I'm using:

```
$pdf->Annotation(20, 20, 5, 5, 'Excel document', array(
    'Subtype' => 'FileAttachment', 
    'Name'    => 'PushPin', 
    'FS'      => 'document.xlsx'
));
```

This uses the build-in "PushPin" graphic as symbol for the Excel, which doesn't look that nice (and only works in Adobe Acrobat?).

Is there a way to link an image to an embedded file in some way?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code should insert the file.

There are only 4 icons for attachments that can be used: *Graph*, *Paperclip*, *PushPin*, *Tag*.

[Lines of code in tcpdf.php](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/64fc19439863e1b1314487a72a74d9bfd0b55a53/tcpdf.php#L8501):

```
$iconsapp = array('Graph', 'Paperclip', 'PushPin', 'Tag');
if (isset($pl['opt']['name']) AND in_array($pl['opt']['name'], $iconsapp)) {
    $annots .= ' /Name /'.$pl['opt']['name'];
} else {
    $annots .= ' /Name /PushPin';
}
```

My impression is that this is not a TCPDF issue. The PDF format only allows those 4 icons. Have a look at this [guide](https://www.wikihow.com/Attach-a-File-to-a-PDF-Document), picture 8. Acrobat Pro also seems to support those icons.

Hint: [TCPDF Example 41](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_041/) demonstrate the attachment. However the PushPin does not get shown in the pdf viewer. I don't know why.